# Why does > selector also choose a nested span?

Tags: html, css

Something obvious I may be missing, but I can't figure out why the > selector (which should only select direct children), also styles the nested span #2.
[image]

I do get the expected result (only outer span #1 green, span #2 is black) when I add this to the CSS:

```css
span{
  color:black;
}
```

However, I feel it's odd that using just the > selector somehow expands into the nested span, behaving as a space selector targeting **all** children:

```css
div span{
  color:green;
}
```

Any ideas? ([Here's a Codepen](https://codepen.io/anzuj/pen/ZEYOXaL) I used to fiddle with it)

Comment: because the child of the span gets the parent's color. Basically how you assign a color to the body tag and all the elements in the body get that color. Only way to get the span inside to be black is to assign a rule with higher specificity.

Comment: Thank you! This explains it. Quite a peculiar situation though. You live, you learn!

Comment: That is how "Cascading" styles sheets work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, [Inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance). The style isn't applying **directly** to the second span. Rather, the second span is "**inheriting**" its style from the first span.

Look in something like Chrome Dev tools and you'll see this;

[image]

Your options here are limited. You could unset any nested spans by resetting them to their initial state;

```css
body{
  color: red;
}

div > span{
  color: green;
}

div > span > span{
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>
    This is span #1
    <span>This is span #2</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

However, this comes with a caveat. This means it **won't inherit from anything**. Note how it doesn't inherit the red color from the body.

Comment: Oh, how interesting! How would you amend the code in order to achieve the expected result (preventing nested span to inherit)?

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: `div > span > span` This is rather specific, On a larger scale you'd rather have the property rest for all span elements `span{ color:initial }`